# Concatenate two layers Tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am new to TensorflowJS and I try to code something but I am stuck...

I have two input layers like that:

```js
const input1 = tf.input({ shape: [64, 64, 3] });
const input2 = tf.input({ shape: [1536] });
```

The first one is for an image of 64 by 64 and the 3 is for RGB.
The second one is for an array that contains 1536 numbers (floats).

I tried to concatenate them with `.concatenate().apply(input1, input2)` but got the following error:

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got input shapes: [[null,64,64,3],[null,1536]]
```

I also tried to add `{ axis: -1 }` or `{ axis: 1 }` (found that on stack overflow but that doesnt work too).

I also tried that (answer by chat gpt) :

```
const flatten1 = tf.layers.flatten().apply(input1);
const flatten2 = tf.layers.flatten().apply(input2);
const concat = tf.layers.concatenate({ axis: -1 }).apply([flatten1, flatten2]);
```

but same error...

Can someone help me? I just want to add this to my `tf.sequential()` as an input...

PS: This is the module I use:
`const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');`

Comment: It tells you why though, `(...) matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got input shapes: [[null,64,64,3],[null,1536]]`. If you have a 1D array, concat() would be extending the length, if you have 2D array, the height (same width) or the width (same height), if you have 3D the depth (width and height constant) etc...So you have to have the same shape except for that dimension.

Comment: I don’t understand what I am supposed to change…

Comment: Answered with what I get from your post, feel free to ask whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

This just shows you what concatenation is, and how can be done for those specific inputs.

This is a textual description of the code at the bottom of the post:

- create an image-like shape `(width, height, colorChannels)`
- create a random one dimensional array (aka vector) of 1536 values
- 1536 elements can be reshaped into a little "image" of 8 x 64 and 3 channels
- Result is 72 x 64 x 8 so this should hint you what the code did (extend the axis with different number of values, that is it.

```js
const original = tf.ones([64, 64, 3]);
const random = tf.randomNormal([1536]);
 
const reshaped = tf.reshape(random, [8, 64, 3]);

const axis = 0;
const concat = tf.concat([original, reshaped], axis);

console.log(concat);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

Another possibility is flat, extend and then back re-shape but I find this simple enough.

Comment: But then when I do `model.add(concat)` (`const model = tf.sequential();`) it throws me the error : `if (layer.inboundNodes.length === 0) {

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`
So the error is located when I do the model.add

Comment: I am just showing you the logical basic behind, i.e how to concatenate 2 tensors. For sequential, you  do not specify an input in that way: _Note: input is only necessary when using model. When using sequential, specify inputShape for the first layer or use inputLayer as the first layer._ [See the docs](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#input)